# Zbar not working after changing setSymbology

Tags: ios, zbar-sdk

I want Zbar  to capture images as well as scan QR code with the single Zbar reader without dismissing it from the current ViewController.

For that I was using

```
[reader.scanner setSymbology:ZBAR_QRCODE config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE to:1];
```

to enable when the slider changes to the QR code mode and

```
[reader.scanner setSymbology:ZBAR_QRCODE config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE to:0];
```

to disable the QR code mode when the slider is set to certain value.

It is not working properly by changing like that. If the QR code is enabled initially, the zbar reader scans well the QR code.

But I wanna show just an image picker initially, so I put on the above code that disables the QR code mode and would change the `symbology` as needed. By changing the symbology, the QR code is not working. Can someone please help me fixing this showing me what went wrong?

Im working on [the latest release](http://nchc.dl.sourceforge.net/project/zbar/iPhoneSDK/ZBarSDK-1.2.dmg) with iOS 6.0. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You would have probably solved the problem by now.   The problem is hard to imagine though but one of either solution will solve it:

1. Use ZBarReaderController instead of the ZBar ReaderViewController so you have control when the barcode gets captured. (The symbology support is set once before you initialise
   the controller I do not believe you can change symbology support dynamically, also since you only disabled QR Codes - it will continue to support the other 20 or so barcode formats.
2. If you want to pick images from the camera roll you need to do it outside the Z bar reader controller but you should still be able to decode the resulting image using Z-Bar - it should be easy to figure out in the sample app.